# Python Twill: follow link and grab data

Tags: python, web-crawler, twill

I finally arrived to open a page and make the request I want.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from twill.commands import *

go("http://www.website.com/")
code(200) # assert page loaded fine
showforms()
# Make a search
searchStr = '%s' % n
formvalue(1, 'q', searchStr)
submit('Factorize!')
links = showlinks()
```

I now see all the links listed and I would like to click on the number `11` and `12` and when I'm there grab 1 value per page.

How to use `follow()` and what's the command used for grabbing a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

```
data = urllib2.urlopen(follow(str(3)))
```

where `'3'` is is the number of the link listed by `links = showlinks()`